# How do append my API results into an unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

Ok so I am trying to get this Function:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=starcraft&limit=30&&type=top&callback=?", function (data) {
  var temp = "";

  $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
      temp = temp + "<ul><a target='iframe1' href='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.name + "'>" + item.channel.display_name + "</a></ul>";

    });
  $("#list ul ").html(temp);
});
```

to populate in a list inside the unorderd list here:

```
<li>SC2
<ul>

</ul>
</li>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: why do you use <ul><a.... just use <a....

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y25Lq/1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for an unordered list is `<ul><li></li></ul>`. Each element of your list will be wrapped in its own `<li>`.

What you are probably looking for is

```
var myList = $("#list ul");
$.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
  var temp = $("<li><a target='iframe1' href='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.name + "'>" + item.channel.display_name + "</a></li>");

  myList.add(temp);
});
```

The result you are looking for is
    `<ul><li>SC2</li></ul>`